# Chat suspension - does it work?

Tags: discussion, chat

Okay, so I have been suspended twice in the past year. I can't remember the exact details but roughly the following was what happened:

hh:mm posting a picture of a monkey/hitler in a dress out of boredom

hh:mm + ~10 min chatting as normal

hh:mm + ~20 min went away to make some snack, BBQ some marinated meat

hh:mm + ~50 minutes coming back to the screen, was told by the chat that I was banned for 2 minutes

Went back to rotate the meat on the BBQ, making a drink

Came back to the PC ... the ban was long gone.

Now, auto chat bans takes 5 flags. For something that is not really offensive, it could take up to an hour for the ban to kick in. By then the poster could be long gone.

And the ban itself only lasts half an hour.

It's a bit like trying to slap a running horse. By the time you sight the horse and try to land your hand on its juicy butt, it already went by and all you get to touch is the tip of its tail.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Yes, notification is needed to let the users know that they were suspended if they were not around when the suspension was in place. So no suspension would ever be missed again!

Answer (score 13):

Just in case you are not trolling and really don't know (or,  more likely, to other users who will read it in the future and ignore the trolling), there is automatic chat suspension that lasts 30 minutes. Not 2 minutes, and not 2 hours.

So it means that in "ab:xy + ~22" (whatever it means) the last vote has been cast on a flag on your chat message, and 30 minutes ban was triggered on your chat account. The clock started ticking.

When you came back ~28 minutes later, there were only 2 minutes left. Simple as that.

Comment: ab is the hr, xy is the min, ~ means about. HTH.

Comment: @chmod711telkitty VCSR!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it does.  These short chat suspensions help to keep SO chatters alive.  When a user gets very hungry/thirsty/exhausted, their 'normal' level of self-control is suppressed and they tend to post something inappropriate and get suspended.  This gives them a chance to rest/eat/drink, so preventing collapse, coma and death from inattention to essential life-support activity.

Comment: But ... wait, weight loss industry would disagree! Maybe you are sabotaging your online enemies diet by making them eat more. Devious, Jame, devious!!

Comment: @chmod711telkitty weight loss industry is not welcome here. We routinely destroy anything they post.

Answer (score 4):

Bans are not at intended to "notify" the banned user.

They're not to impress them, or make them feel bad. They're mostly there to *protect* the rest of the users.

It's super cool that you prefer the "drive-by" style of trolling. And it's also fine if you crave the validation of a ban so much that you are unhappy if miss it.

*Bans are not a reward for successful trolling and the lack of notification is a feature in this respect.* ¹

Don't forget there are also the high-intensity trolls that derail a chat room and generally make it unusable for a prolonged period of time.

That's aptly prevented by small, time-limited bans.

---

¹ inb4 Request for badges on repeated bans

Comment: I think we should make it harder, only award badges to the repeated banned if one scores more than 5 temp chat bans in a year without any bans longer than a day. Maybe call the badge 'Elite Dodger'?

Comment: Sure. I dunno what would  be dodged. More like "Proven Jackass"